# UILocalNotification - mutable copying

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nscopying

**Overview:**

- I am copying an instance of `UILocalNotification` and making changes to it to the newly created instance
- Then I schedule the newly created instance of `UILocalNotification`

**How I am copying**

- I am copying the instance of `UILocalNotification` by invoking the method `copy`

**Question**

1. Am I doing the correct thing or should I be using a different method to create a mutable copy. (`mutableCopy` is not implemented for `UILocalNotification`
2. Does copy actually do a mutable copy ?
3. Is it necessary to create a copy at all, will `scheduleLocalNotification:` create a new copy anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, `copy`'s fine.
2. `mutableCopy` generally applies to types which distinguish immutable and mutable flavors. since the type does not make that distinction, `copy` is 'mutable'.
3. typically, you would assume that you should need to copy the argument. in this case, the docs specify that `scheduleLocalNotification:` creates a copy of the parameter. explicitly copying is not strictly necessary.

Comment: thank you so much Justin !! well explained if you have the time I have one more doubt - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359024/uilocalnotification-repeatinterval-reset-no-repeat