# UILocalNotification - repeatInterval reset (no repeat)

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

**Overview**

- I am creating a notification based on an existing instance of `UILocalNotification`
- Existing instance has `repeatInterval` set to `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`

**What I want to do**

- I want to set `repeatInterval` to no repeat,

**Question**

- What is the constant that I should set `repeatInterval` to in order for it not to repeat ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from Apple documentation:

> If you assign an calendar unit such as weekly (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or
>   yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system reschedules the notification
>   for delivery at the specified interval. **The default value is 0, which
>   means don't repeat.**

I assume you want to cancel the notification with the repeating interval, you can do that in two ways:

1. Cancel **all** the notifications.
2. Cancel **only that notification.**

The first option is easy, use:

```
cancelAllLocalNotifications
```

In your app delegate.

The second one requires more work. You need to go through the pending notifications (use `scheduledLocalNotifications`) and cancel the notification.

In order to know which notifications is going to be canceled you can use the `userInfo` property when you set the notification. For example set an unique ID for every notification so when you cancel that notification you simply compare that ID with all the IDs in your `scheduledLocalNotifications` array.

Comment: Thank you so much Edu, well explained !!

Comment: my notification set to notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day but i am unable to reschedule the notification @Edu